# Почему у меня не работают boundary timers (использую Activiti 6)?

Tags: java, alfresco

Не срабатывают boundary timers. Использую Activiti 6. Если ставлю что-то после таймера, то процесс идёт по своему обычному маршруту. Если ничего не ставлю, идёт из ветки, исходящей из таймера. При этом без разницы, какой промежуток времени стоит у таймера: процесс идёт по той или по другой ветке сразу же.
Кусок моей bpm-схемы с таймером:
[image: схема с boundary timer]

Для создания объектов для работы с движком Активити использую Spring 5. Вот часть моего класса конфигурации:

```
@Bean
    SpringProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration(@Qualifier("dataSourceForActiviti") DataSource dataSourceForActiviti,
                                                                @Qualifier("transactionManagerForActiviti") PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerForActiviti) {
        SpringProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration = new SpringProcessEngineConfiguration();
        processEngineConfiguration.setTransactionManager(transactionManagerForActiviti);

        processEngineConfiguration.setDataSource(dataSourceForActiviti)
                .setDatabaseSchemaUpdate(ProcessEngineConfiguration.DB_SCHEMA_UPDATE_TRUE)
                .setAsyncExecutorActivate(true)
        ;

        processEngineConfiguration.setDeploymentResources(new Resource[]{
                new ClassPathResource("bpm/LicensingProcess.bpmn20.xml"),
                new ClassPathResource("bpm/ReissuanceLicenseProcess.bpmn20.xml"),
                new ClassPathResource("bpm/IssueOfDuplicateProcess.bpmn20.xml"),
                new ClassPathResource("bpm/IssuanceOfCopyProcess.bpmn20.xml"),
                new ClassPathResource("bpm/TerminationOfLicenseProcess.bpmn20.xml"),
                new ClassPathResource("bpm/ExtractFromRegisterOfLicensesProcess.bpmn20.xml")
        });


        return processEngineConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean
    ProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngineFactoryBean(SpringProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration) {
        ProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngineFactoryBean = new ProcessEngineFactoryBean();
        processEngineFactoryBean.setProcessEngineConfiguration(processEngineConfiguration);
        return processEngineFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    RepositoryService repositoryService(ProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngineFactoryBean) throws Exception {
        return processEngineFactoryBean.getObject().getRepositoryService();
    }

    @Bean
    RuntimeService runtimeService(ProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngineFactoryBean) throws Exception {
        return processEngineFactoryBean.getObject().getRuntimeService();
    }

    @Bean
    TaskService taskService(ProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngineFactoryBean) throws Exception {
        return processEngineFactoryBean.getObject().getTaskService();
    }
```

Я пробовал использовать метод `setAsyncExecutorActivate`, и передавал в качестве аргумента и `true`, и `false` - и разницы не заметил. Хотя в документации сказано, что нужно устанавливать значение `asyncExecutorActivate` в `true`

PS Нашёл такое решение (добавляется в опредление бина `ProcessEngineConfiguration`):

```
// Async Job Executor
final DefaultAsyncJobExecutor asyncExecutor = new DefaultAsyncJobExecutor();
asyncExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(50);
asyncExecutor.setQueueSize(100);
processEngineConfiguration.setAsyncExecutor(asyncExecutor);
```

Но оно также не помогает мне. Хотя после добавления этого кода `asyncJobExecutor` уже не равен `null`

PSS В тоже время, подобная схема прекрасно работает в Activiti Modeler. И я пока не могу понять, поэтому это хорошо работает там и не работает у меня.

PSSS Написал простенькое приложение без спринга (на свинге). Использовал класс `StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration`, не использовал `ProcessEngineBeanFactoryBean`. И тоже всё работало. Но только пока после `boundary timer`-а не стоит `script task` или `service task`. С ними - не работает (по первому не находит движок груви, по второму - не видит указанный класс (причём указываю полное имя класса, и он там точно есть)). Если после `boundary timer` стоит `user task` или `manual task`, то всё нормально отрабатывает. Почему не работает с `script task` и `service task` я таки и не понял. Осталось попробовать с классами `SpringProcessEngineConfiguration` и `ProcessEngineBeanFactoryBean`, и с контейнером бинов спринга.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таймеры не работают, когда параллельно запущен Activiti Modeler, использующий ту же базу. При выключении этого приложение всё начинает работать.